# Use-case for push without tracking

Tags: git, push

When I push a purely local branch to a remote in SmartGit, it asks me whether to configure tracking. I always select to configure it, because I don't understand why one should not configure tracking at all.

Are there use-cases where pushing a branch *without* configuring tracking makes sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You pull from remote1, but you push to remote2.

You can track only one remote. If you track remote1, then you cannot track remote2 at the same time.

Comment: When does this happen (push to but not pull from remote2)?